# _getParam('paramName') encoding issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, utf-8

My php application attempts to get a description param from the url that hits it: for example

```
http://example.co.uk/events/errnc8/promo.html?description=Leicester%27s+finest+to+close+this+year%27s+Glastonbury&#38;
```

But when I call

```
$description = $this->_getParam('description');
```

I end up with $description being set as

```
Leicester&#39;s finest to close this year&#39;s Glastonbury
```

What's the best way to properly encode/decode this parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$description = html_entity_decode($this->_getParam('description'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

This will decode the html entities but this looks like a massive XSS security flaw if you're planning on just echoing that value without any sanitising (unless the _getParam() method sanitises input)

Comment: This works for me: and thanks for raising the security issue, I'll go raise that with someone who knows more than me :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

You should use that standardised function to make the most out of php's own libraries.

```
string htmlspecialchars_decode ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 ] )
```